# Fate vs. Prayer: Everything happens the way Allah intended, then why make dua?

Tags: dua, qadar

**Assalamu Alaikum.**

My doubt is regarding making duas. We have been known that Allah has knowledge of our present and our past and everything which happened and will happen has been recorded or written in a clear record (Al‑Lawh Al‑Mahfooz)

> *“And with Him are the keys of the Ghayb (all that is hidden), none knows them but He. And He knows whatever there is in the land and in the sea; not a leaf falls, but He knows it. There is not a grain in the darkness of the earth nor anything fresh or dry, but is written in a **Clear Record**” [[al-An’aam 6:59](https://quran.com/6/59/)]*
>
> *“No calamity befalls on the earth or in yourselves but it is inscribed in the **Book of Decrees** (Al‑Lawh Al‑Mahfooz) before We bring it into existence. Verily, that is easy for Allaah” [[al-Hadeed 57:22](https://quran.com/57/22/)]*

If everything has already been recorded and has been happening based on it. then why should one need to make duas?

Just consider this an example. If I had a wish to buy a car by next month. I prayed to Allah to make my wish come true. there are two possibilities. either I get it or I won't. if I buy it, its because Allah accepted my dua and Allah has already willed to make my dua come true. and the other possibility is, I won't buy it and because Allah had never willed to happen.

Even another person, just like me had a wish to buy a car, but he never prayer, still to him there are two possibilities: either he buys it because Allah willed to make it happen, or else he won't buy because Allah wouldn't have willed to make it happen.

I mean all these are already been recorded in the **book of decrees (Al‑Lawh Al‑Mahfooz)** then what's the point in making dua, as everything will only happen based on it?

And there is a hadith which says that nothing of our deeds, actions, and livelihood will be going to be different as nothing could be added or subtracted from our destiny.

**[Sahih Muslim, Book of destiny, hadith no. 6392](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/46/3)**

> *Hudhaifa b. Usaid reported directly from Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) that lie said: When the drop of (semen) remains in the womb for forty or fifty (days) or forty nights, the angel comes and says: My Lord, will he be good or evil? And both these things would be written. Then the angel says: My Lord, would he be male or female? And both these things are written. And his deeds and actions, his death, his livelihood; these are also recorded. Then his document of destiny is rolled and there is no, addition to and subtraction from it.*

Comment: Allah swt has given us free will and the capability to think. Why would we have these faculties if everything in our life was determined? There are things which are determined like our gender, when and where we are born and when and where we will die, but we can influence  other aspects of our life. Dua asks Allah for His support in achieving what we decided to achieve. Either He gives it to us or He withholds it and gives something better. Regardless of our whishes being fulfilled or not, we  achieve more closeness to Allah swt as we do dua  which means we think of Him and talk to Him.

Comment: If our death has already been determined then its against our free will.. I think you may be familiar with the grand father paradox.The grandfather paradox is a paradox of time travel in which inconsistencies emerge through changing the past. The name comes from the paradox's common description: a person travels to the past and kills their own grandfather before the conception of their father or mother, which prevents the time traveler's existence.Despite its title, the grandfather paradox does not exclusively regard the contradiction of killing one's own grandfather to prevent one's birth.

Comment: So if u were to say that my death was already defined by God then I think we don't have free will.. because if he determines my death then it is he who has to determine the way I die. 

If a person were to die on an accident, we may think Allah had determined accident to be his death. Then I think it's wrong because it was that person's decision to be there at that time when that accident happend.. if we were to think its really God who planned to take his life there.. [continue]

Comment: Then I think it would be illogical if you consider this way.
I have a knife and you are in front of me. It's my decision to kill you now or not. You may be lucky sometimes by escaping by miracles. Not always miracle happens. And hence it's my decision to kill you or not. So ur death is defined by my will too. If you think Its not my will and its only determined by God then if I kill you. My act also has to be determined by God to take your life (logically). @Noor

Comment: I've heard a number of Islamic teologicians say that such a concept of pre-determined fate/destiny has nothing to do with true Islam, and specifically with Qoran. The hadits implying this should be regarded as either fake or at least contradicting with Qoran, and therefore should be neglected on the grounds that nothing said or done by God's Messenger can supersede God's Word as reflected in Qoran (which is God's Word indirectly) as well as the entire nature and universe that surround us (which is God's Word directly).

Comment: @Sadi Believing in fate has been a pillar of Eemaan. How could it be false? It would be good if u could enlighten your points.

Comment: I think it's OK if you mean "nothing happens in the universe against and/or outside God's will". But saying that every single incident is somewhat written like a film scenario before a baby is born, I am sure, would be in total contrast to individual responsibility for one's deeds in life! I can safely say there's no such a rule as believing in such "fate" anywhere in Qoran unless and until somebody cites a text from Qoran, not anywhere else. For instance, the pillars of faith/eeman are listed in Qoran Nida:136 as (believing in) God, angels, books, messenger, and judgement day.

Comment: This is a big problem in Islam (and other religions). There is a holy book, and all other texts must be in line with it! If not, they are either fake or involve human error. Nothing in those texts may contradict with or supersede the contents of the holy book. And all the contents of the holy book should be interpreted as an integral whole, without contradicting one another, but complemeting one another, sometimes requiring to consider the context, the ciscumstances of each. So even one cannot simply take one phrase from the holy book and use it in contradiction with another phrase there.